# Send Button Name From MainActivity to Fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-tabs

I'm new in Android Studio JAVA development and this is my first project and expérience with both JAVA and android studio.
My problem is that I'm trying to send the Button Name by double-clicked from the Main Activity called **BardoMap** to a Tab fragment ( to specific Fragment called **EnglishBardoFragment** ) so I can use the Name button to call some data from the FireBase.
I tried to use Bundle at all but I couldn't find the right solution to only send the button name to the Fragment I manage to do all the rest of the work  can anyone please help me with some idea or information about how to that value from the activity to the specific fragment

this is the code of the MainActivity **BardoMap**

```
public class BardoMap extends AppCompatActivity   {
     private Button AddBardobtn;
     private Button BackB;
     private Button SavePositionB;
     private ViewGroup rootLayout;
     private int _xDelta;
     private int _yDelta;
     private int X ;
     private int Y ;

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    DatabaseReference savig;
    Button   button1;
    int i = 0 ;
    int j  ;

    public String NameButton;
     private    long startTime ;
    private  int clickCount;
    private long duration ;
    static final int MAX_DURATION = 500;
    List<Button> Listbuttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bardo_map);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("SIDE",2);

        savig = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.view_root);
        SavePositionB = findViewById(R.id.SavePositionB);


        relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.view_root);
         FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction t = manager.beginTransaction();
        EnglishBardoFragment engB = new EnglishBardoFragment();

       DatabaseReference usersRef = savig.child("Positions");
       usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               if ( snapshot.exists())
                {

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                          i++;
                           String uid = snapshot1.getKey();
                           BeaconsPosition _Position = new BeaconsPosition();
                           button1 = new Button(BardoMap.this);

                        button1.setId(i);
                        button1.setText(uid);

                        _Position.setXPosition(snapshot1.child("xposition").getValue().toString());
                        _Position.setYPosition(snapshot1.child("yposition").getValue().toString());
                        float x=Float.parseFloat( _Position.getXPosition());
                        float y=Float.parseFloat( _Position.getYPosition());
                        button1.setX(x);
                        button1.setY(y);
                        button1.setTag("DragingObject");
                        Listbuttons.add(button1);
                        button1.setLayoutParams(new
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                         if (relativeLayout != null){
                            relativeLayout.addView(button1);


                             button1 = ((Button) findViewById(i));


                             button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                     int X = (int) event.getRawX();
                                     int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
                                     switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
                                     {
                                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParms = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                                             _xDelta = X - lParms.leftMargin;
                                             _yDelta = Y - lParms.topMargin;
                                             startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                                             clickCount++;
                                             break;
                                         case  MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                             long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                                             duration = duration + time;
                                             if(clickCount == 2)
                                             {
                                                 if(duration<= MAX_DURATION)
                                                 {
                                                     NameButton = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
                                                     Toast.makeText(BardoMap.this, "double tap " + NameButton,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                                     OpenBardoInsertDataByID();
                                                 }
                                                 clickCount = 0;
                                                 duration = 0;
                                                 break;
                                             }
                                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                                             break;
                                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                                             break;
                                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v .getLayoutParams();
                                             layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                                             layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                                             layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                                             layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                                             v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                                             break;
                                     }
                                     rootLayout.invalidate();

                                     return true;
                                 }


                             });
                        }


                    }

                }


            }

          @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }



        });

        AddBardobtn = findViewById(R.id.AddBeaconB);
        BackB = findViewById(R.id.BackB);
        SavePositionB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              SaveButtonPosition();
            }
        });
        AddBardobtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    OpenBardoInsertData();

            }
        });
        BackB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                  MainMenu();
            }
        });
    }

   private void SaveButtonPosition() {
       for(Button b:Listbuttons) {

                X = (int) b.getX();
                Y = (int) b.getY();
                BeaconsPosition beaconsposition = new BeaconsPosition( String.valueOf(X) ,String.valueOf(Y)  );
                savig.child("Positions").child(b.getText().toString()).setValue(beaconsposition);
                savig.child("0").child("Musees").child("Bardo").child("Beacons").child(b.getText().toString()).child("Position").setValue(beaconsposition);

               Toast.makeText(this, "very good souleima " +Listbuttons.size() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }

    }

    private void MainMenu() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this , MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void OpenBardoInsertData() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this , BardoTab.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void OpenBardoInsertDataByID() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this , BardoTab.class);
        intent.putExtra("NameButton",NameButton);


        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

this is My **SectionsPagerAdapter** for the fragment Tab

```
package com.example.musepourtous.ui.main;



public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private  String NameButton;
    @StringRes
    private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.tab_text_1, R.string.tab_text_2, R.string.tab_text_3};
    private final Context mContext;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      Fragment fragment = null;
      switch (position)
      {
          case 0 :
              fragment  = new EnglishBardoFragment();
              /*Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
              bundle.getString("edttext");
              String test =  bundle.getString("edttext");
              bundle.putString("edttext1", "test");
              fragment.setArguments(bundle);*/
              break;
          case 1 :
              fragment = new FrenchBardo();
              break;
          case 2 :
              fragment = new ArabicBardoFragment();

      }
      return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mContext.getResources().getString(TAB_TITLES[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}
```

and this is my Fragment **EnglishBardoFragment**

```
public class EnglishBardoFragment extends Fragment {
    
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private  EditText UUIDBE , DescBE , TitleBE ;
    private Button SaveDataBE;
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    DatabaseReference myRef ;

    private Button ChooseImageBE;
    private Button CancelBardoBE;
    private ImageView ImageViewBE;
    private ProgressBar ProgressBarBE;
    private ProgressBar ProgressBarBES;

    private Button ChooseSoundBE;



    private Uri ImageUri;
    private Uri SoundUri;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQEST = 1  ;
    private static final int PICK_SOUND_REQEST = 0  ;
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    private StorageReference mStorageRefS;
    private String ImageURLData ;
    private String SoundURLData ;

    private ImageView imagePlayPause;
    private TextView textCurrrentTime , textTotalDuration;
    private SeekBar playerSeekBar ;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final static int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 1;
    String NameButton;


    public EnglishBardoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment EnglishBardoFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static EnglishBardoFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        EnglishBardoFragment fragment = new EnglishBardoFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }
    private static final String[] REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS = new String[] {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE };
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        checkPermissions();

        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Images");
        mStorageRefS = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Sounds");
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_english_bardo, null);
        UUIDBE = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.UUIDBardoE);

        TitleBE = view.findViewById(R.id.TitleBardoE);

        DescBE = view.findViewById(R.id.DescriptionBardoE);
        SaveDataBE = view.findViewById(R.id.AddBeaconBE);
        ChooseImageBE = view.findViewById(R.id.CHooseImageBardoE);
        ImageViewBE = view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewBE);
        ProgressBarBE = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        ProgressBarBES = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_barA);
        ChooseSoundBE = view.findViewById(R.id.CHooseSoundBardoE);
        imagePlayPause = view.findViewById(R.id.imagePlayPause);
        textCurrrentTime = view.findViewById(R.id.textCurrentTime);
        textTotalDuration = view.findViewById(R.id.textTotalDuration);
        playerSeekBar = view.findViewById(R.id.playerSeekBar);
        CancelBardoBE = view.findViewById(R.id.CancelBardoBE);


        mediaPlayer =  new MediaPlayer();
        playerSeekBar.setMax(100);
        imagePlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ( mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(updater);
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    imagePlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                    updateSeekBar();
                }
                else
                {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    imagePlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                    updateSeekBar();
                }

            }
        });


     

        return view;
    }

    private void preapareMediaPlayer(Uri path)
    {

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), path);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                textTotalDuration.setText(milliSecondToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));

            }catch (Exception exception){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }




    }
    private Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateSeekBar();
            long currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            textCurrrentTime.setText(milliSecondToTimer(currentDuration));
        }
    };
    private void updateSeekBar()
    {
    if ( mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        playerSeekBar.setProgress((int) (((float) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / mediaPlayer.getDuration()) * 100));
        handler.postDelayed(updater,1000);
    }
    }   
    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent , PICK_IMAGE_REQEST);

    }
    private void openSoundChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("audio/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent , PICK_SOUND_REQEST);

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if( requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null )
        {
            ImageUri = data.getData() ;
            Picasso.get().load("ImageUri").into(ImageViewBE);
            Picasso.get().load(ImageUri).into(ImageViewBE);

        }

      else  if( requestCode == PICK_SOUND_REQEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null )
        {

            SoundUri = data.getData() ;



            preapareMediaPlayer(SoundUri);



        }

    }



    private void UploadImage() {
        if (ImageUri != null )
        {
           final StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(UUIDBE.getText().toString());
           fileReference.putFile(ImageUri)
                   .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                           Handler handler = new Handler();
                           handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                               @Override
                               public void run() {
                                   ProgressBarBE.setProgress(0);
                               }
                           } ,  500);
                           fileReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                               @Override
                               public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                   Uri downloadUrl = uri;
                                   ImageURLData = downloadUrl.toString();
                                   AddBeaconsBE();

                               }
                           });

                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Upload Image  Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                       }
                   })
                   .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   })
                   .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Upload Image in progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount() );
                           ProgressBarBE.setProgress((int) progress);
                       }

                   })
           .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

               }
           });




        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Image Selected - Please Select Image before saving data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }




    public void AddBeaconsBE(){
        String UUIDBeacon = UUIDBE.getText().toString();
        String TitleBeacon = TitleBE.getText().toString();
        String DescriptionBeacon = DescBE.getText().toString();
        //Displaying Toast with Hello Javatpoint message

        if ( !TextUtils.isEmpty(UUIDBeacon) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(TitleBeacon) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(DescriptionBeacon))
        {
            String id = UUIDBeacon;

            DataBeacon beacons = new DataBeacon( UUIDBeacon , TitleBeacon , DescriptionBeacon , ImageURLData , SoundURLData , UUIDBE.getText().toString().trim() );

            myRef.child("0").child("Musees").child("Bardo").child("Beacons").child(id).setValue(beacons);




            BeaconsPosition beaconsposition = new BeaconsPosition( "191" ,"360"  );
            myRef.child("0").child("Musees").child("Bardo").child("Beacons").child(id).child("Position").setValue(beaconsposition);
            myRef.child("Positions").child(id).setValue(beaconsposition);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Beacon Added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            UUIDBE.setText("");
            TitleBE.setText("");
            DescBE.setText("");
            ImageViewBE.setImageResource(0);
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            textTotalDuration.setText("0:0");
            imagePlayPause.setActivated(false);

        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(UUIDBeacon)) {
            UUIDBE.setError("Please Enter The UUID");
            return;
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(TitleBeacon)) {
            TitleBE.setError("Please Enter The TITLE");
            return;
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(DescriptionBeacon)) {
            DescBE.setError("Please Enter The DESCRIPTION");
            return;
        }

    }
    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver cR =  getActivity().getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    }

    protected void checkPermissions() {
        final List<String> missingPermissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        // check all required dynamic permissions
        for (final String permission : REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS) {
            final int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), permission);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                missingPermissions.add(permission);
            }
        }
        if (!missingPermissions.isEmpty()) {
            // request all missing permissions
            final String[] permissions = missingPermissions
                    .toArray(new String[missingPermissions.size()]);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), permissions, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        } else {
            final int[] grantResults = new int[REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS.length];
            Arrays.fill(grantResults, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            onRequestPermissionsResult(REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS, REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS,
                    grantResults);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                for (int index = permissions.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
                    if (grantResults[index] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // exit the app if one permission is not granted


                        return;
                    }
                }

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: This is the interface of bardoMap activity that I'm talking about and on yellow is the button that I double click to send there Name to Fragment]

[image: this is the interface of fragment tabs that I want to send the Value button to it so I can fill the Texfiled with the data]

PS: I delete some Unesesery function from my code because of the maximum code line that's why some function are culled but don't exist

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using **PowerPreference**

I did this in my MainActivity

```
 NameButton = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
 PowerPreference.getDefaultFile().putString("key",NameButton);
```

Then I called it the fragment

```
value = PowerPreference.getDefaultFile().getString("key", NameButton);
```